# Please help identifying board game similar to Mouse Trap

Tags: identify-this-game

This is a game from likely the 70's or 80's. A board game similar to Mouse Trap in that, you set up a bunch of precarious pieces, and at the end the sequence is triggered and all the pieces jump or spin or do whatever they do. Except this game involved a circus I think. I recall 2 circus performers spinning around a pole, opposite each other, from the top downward.

It is a fleeting memory, and has been bugging me for years!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [here](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/739495/finding-old-mousetrap-like-game-about-a-circus) on board game geek a reference to Flying Finnegan.

It was a circus game like mouse trap.